# Script to add title and it's value for all anchor tag in an HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, title

I am trying to implement a scenario where I have a HTML document with 115 links in it. All links do not have a title attribute in it.

```
<a href="/rek/index.html">REK</a>
```

What I want to achieve here is to add a title for all these anchor tags and the value would be as follows:

```
<a href="/rek/index.html" title="REK">REK</a>
```

This means that the title attribute's value has to be the text of the link. I know how to add a title attribute to all the links using JAVASCRIPT but I'm not able to add the value to it according to the link text.

Can anyone please suggest me a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this :-

```
$('a').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('title',$(this).text());  //or use $.trim($(this).text()) to remove white spaces.
});
```

---

Or if you want to add title attribute only on those anchor tags which **doesn't have title attribute** then try this :-

```
$('a:not([title])').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('title',$(this).text());  //or use $.trim($(this).text()) to remove white spaces.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @kartikeya, just one more question. Would this avoid adding title to links that have the title attribute already in it?

Comment: @CodeKaro....no it will add anchor's text as title even if it has title already or not..

Comment: @CodeKaro ***if you want to keep original title if already set*** you could use instead: `$('a:not([title])').attr('title', function(){
    return this.innerHTML.trim();
});`   http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3